# Getting String value using JsonPath Java

Tags: java, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

Im using JsonPath to Assert on some of the values returned from an api response but having a small issue with asserting the response.

Heres the response i get:

[{"Id":75969,StartDate":"2016-07-01","EndDate":"2021-04-30","duration":5640}]

Lets say i want to Assert on the Start date. 
The method I created looks like this:

```
   public void checkStartDate(String expectedStartDate) {

    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();

    JsonPath values = new JsonPath(responseBody);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedStartDate,values.getString("startDate"));
}
```

The expectedStartDate that i pass in to the method is 2016-07-01 and the date i get back from the JsonPath object is [2016-07-01] which causes the assertion to fail.

Does anyone know what i can do to with JsonPath in order to remove the square braces from the value that im extracting from the response string?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Try the below code :

```
  public void checkStartDate(String expectedStartDate) {
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    String startDate = JsonPath.read(responseBody, "$.[0].StartDate");
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedStartDate, startDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read with "getList", you will get the exact value.

```
    JsonPath values = new JsonPath(responseBody);
    List<String> valuesToRead = values.getList("StartDate");
    for (String value : valuesToRead) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the reponse is an array of objects, rather than just a single object?  So you want to check against `jp.getString("[0].StartDate")`

Working example:

```
JsonPath jp = JsonPath.from("[{\"Id\":75969,\"StartDate\":\"2016-07-01\",\"EndDate\":\"2021-04-30\",\"duration\":5640}]");
System.out.println("2016-07-01".equals(jp.getString("[0].StartDate")));
```

Prints: `true`